# Freya does not give notification when I plug my USB drive. How do I active it like on Gnome 3?

Tags: release-freya

Freya does not give notification when I plug my USB drive. How do I active it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because it was never intended to be possible. Due to security concerns, the elementary devs decided that the default behaviour when plugging in an external drive was to keep it unmounted and leave it to the user what to do with it.

Questionable as it may be, it is a design choice. What I personally find less justifiable is that the volume does not get mounted even if you drag a file on it, which to me is a bug, [but it has been currently labelled as "wishlist".](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1362041)

Comment: citation needed on that first paragraph? Re: dragging, that is a bug to everyone and why it was been marked as "confirmed" ;)

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but I'm not looking for auto mount but just a notification when I plug it in. But may be it needs to be mounted to give notification like you said.

Comment: @DanielForé you ask me? :) I remember talking about this (probably with you) on G+. I don't think I can find an authorative source for that statement..

Comment: @GiulioSant I can't think of any security problems off the top of my head unless it would be auto-running scripts or something which I think is a separate issue. Would appreciate if you'd edit your answer saying that it's a design choice unless you can cite something :)

Comment: @DanielForé I have found our conversation on G+> https://plus.google.com/105043728733814678193/posts/dtKuMpRhmpx

Comment: Also, see this comment by Cody in a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1211118/comments/2

Comment: Oh interesting. I hadn't seen Cody's comment before.